# Tableau: How to show postcode or zipcode entries

Tags: maps, geocoding, tableau-api

I have an excel file with one column and multiple lines. Each line includes 1 zipcode (or postcode). I’d like tableau to show a small dot on the map for each line depending on where it is on the map.

Comment: Hi. Since there are only postcode, I've added them only. When creating a pie, Tableau seperates postcode and entries very well:http://i.imgur.com/goKuwXE.png, however when trying to map them, this is what I see:

Comment: This is what it looks like when using the map, stating 1 entry per only 4 postcodes it recognizes, rather than 1 dot per full postcode: http://i.imgur.com/muWjf4G.png (this is in the UK and tableau is supposed to recognize them.

Comment: Instead of using the generated lat and lon fields, try dragging your postal code pill onto a new sheet (not on the row or column).

Comment: @Bernardo: Not sure I was doing it right, but I created a new sheet and dragged it - it gets converted into lon/lat and then shows the same thing - limited amount of postcodes. What am I doing wrong ? :)

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook?

Comment: @Bernardo sure. Thanks :) http://www.filedropper.com/testdata1

Comment: That is strange. I could not get it to work either. But I did find this that may help you. http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2015/06/01/uk-filled-map-geocoding-pack-for-tableau/

Answer (score 0):

Currently (9.3.3) Tableau doesn't allow mapping full UK postcodes by default. (*From the screenshot you attached it looks like you are using UK postcodes.*)

To show your postcodes on the map you could either:

1. Use the outward postcode (i.e. AB1 from the postcode AB1 2BC) by
   using a calculated field:

   `//UK Outward Postcode`
   `LEFT([UK Postcode],FIND([UK Postcode]," ")-1)`
2. Find a list of postcodes with corresponding latitude/longitude and
   join it with your data set.
3. Geocode the postcodes, i.e. using `geocode()` function from
   [ggmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf) package in R. Bear in mind that there's a limit on the
   number of free API calls. At this point Google Maps API allows 2500
   of them.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau doesn't have the ability to geocode *full* UK postcodes out of the box. This is because there are, unusually by international standards, far too many of them (early 2.5 million uniques codes).

But you can download the full list of lat/lons for postcodes. One source has been conveniently compiled in tableau format by The Information Lab in [tableaumapping.bi](https://tableaumapping.bi/2014/03/19/uk-full-postcodes/).

You can either incorporate this file in your datasource (if you are linking to a database you can add the file and join on postcode so your data contains lat/lon values that Tableau can map directly) or you can add the complete list as a tableau datasource and blend with your data to get the coordinates.